# RStudio says "large array (xxxxx elements)" but I want to see the array's dimensions instead

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, rstudio

If I run the code below, my Global Environment in RStudio tells me the dimensions for x2 (num [1:10, 1:10, 1:10]).  But for x1, it only says "large array (1000000 elements, 7.6 Mb)".

I want to see the array's dimensions at a glance even for large arrays.  (I know I can run `dim(x1)` to get the dimensions, looking for an "at a glance" solution with RStudio...)

Is there a way to get RStudio to treat even large arrays like it does with smaller arrays?

EDIT: It does show the dimensions if I click the small blue error beside x1, but I'm working with many large arrays and adding/removing from my environment.  I am hoping to make it show the dimensions by default.

```
x1 <- array(0, dim = c(100, 100, 100))
x2 <- array(0, dim = c(10, 10, 10))
```

Comment: if you click on x1 in the environment window you can see the dimensions

Comment: Yes, you are right, but was hoping to make that default.

Comment: ... although if you use 'grid' format to display that window you can't get the dimension info. I agree that it would be helpful for it to show consistent information

Comment: RStudio treats small arrays and large arrays differently. That's why you need to click the arrow to see the details. It's similar to large matrices and large lists also. I'd suggest to just use the `dim(x1)` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this myself, months later.  This code does the trick.

```
mode(x1) <- "numeric"
```